# Convergence of double series involving minimum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, divergent-series

> Determine the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}:|n-m|>10,|m-10|>0}\min\{|n|^{-10},|n-m|^{-10}\}.$$

I tried solving this using "an integral test", saying
$$
\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}:|n-m|>10,|m-10|>0}\min\{|n|^{-10},|n-m|^{-10}\} \le \int_{|x-y|>10,|y-10|>0} \min \{|x|^{-10},|x-y|^{-10}\}dxdy
.$$

However the integral to the right diverges (it's bounded from below by $\int_{-\infty}^{-10}\int_{20}^\infty \min\{...\} dxdy=\iint_{[20,\infty)\times[-\infty,-10)}|x|^{-10}dxdy$ which is divergent). It does not mean however anything as the sum may still be convergent.

Does anybody has an idea how to show this series converges/diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Let me first convince you that the sum converges by investigating a much easier version:

$$ \sum_{(n,m)\neq 0} |n|^{-10}\wedge|m|^{-10} $$

Decomposing the sum over the subregions divided by the lines $m = \pm n$, and exploiting the symmetry, this sum is bounded from above by

$$ 4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-n}^{n} \frac{1}{n^{10}} = 4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n^{10}}, $$

which converges.

---

**2.** Now we move on to the sum in the question. Since the sum $\sum_{|n-10|>10} |n|^{-10} \wedge |n-10|^{-10} $ converges, it suffices to study the convergence of

$$ S := \sum_{|n-m|>10} |n|^{-10} \wedge |n-m|^{-10}. $$

By noting that

$$ |n-m| \geq |n| \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (m \geq 0 \text{ and } n \leq 2m) \text{ or } (m \leq 0 \text{ and } n \geq 2m), $$

$\hspace{80pt}$[image: Regions]

we get

\begin{align*}
S
&\leq 2 \sum_{\substack{|n-m|>10 \\ m \geq 0}} |n|^{-10} \wedge |n-m|^{-10} \\
&\leq 2 \sum_{\substack{|n-m|>10 \\ m \geq 0 \\ n \geq 2m}} |n|^{-10} + 2 \sum_{\substack{|n-m|>10 \\ m \geq 0 \\ n \leq 2m}} |n-m|^{-10} \\
&\leq 2 \sum_{m \geq 0} \sum_{\substack{n \geq m/2 \\ n \neq 0}} |n|^{-10} + 2\sum_{l=11}^{\infty} \frac{\#\{ (n,m) : m=n+l, m \geq 0, n \leq 2m\}}{l^{10}}.
\end{align*}

Now by using the fact that

$$ \sum_{\substack{n \geq m/2 \\ n \neq 0}} |n|^{-10} = \mathcal{O}(m^{-9}) $$

and

$$ \#\{ (n,m) : m=n+l, m \geq 0, n \leq 2m\} = \mathcal{O}(l), $$

it follows that the above upper bound converges.

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov, It is another notation for the minimum, i.e., $x \wedge y = \min\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Okay but one more thing: Why $\sum |n|^{-10}=O(m^{-9})$?

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov, That bound can be obtained using "an integral test": if $m$ is a positive integer and $s > 1$, then $$\sum_{n \geq m} \frac{1}{n^s} \leq \frac{1}{m^s} + \int_{m}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^s} $$ and this upper bound is of order $m^{-(s-1)}$.

Comment: Thanks and why $\#\{(n,m):m=n+l,m\ge0,n\le 2m\}$ is $O(l)$?

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov, I was lazy enough to skip the details on that, but by drawing the region and counting the number of points manually, it is not hard to produce an explicit formula for that number of points, from which we can deduce that bound. Also note that this is very close to the length of part of the line $m=n+l$ contained in the region $m \geq 0$ and $n \leq 2m$.

Comment: @SangchuiLee I think I almost get it now. Can you please elaborate why the convergence of $S$ implies the convergence of the original sum? (actually I think you used it the other way around so the orignsal sum converges and bounds it)

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov, Note that $S$ is obtained by adding $\sum_{|n-10|>10} |n|^{-10} \wedge |n-10|^{-10}$ to the original sum. So, $S$ bounds the original sum from above. Oh, and... I just realized that I made a **typo** in the definition of $S$. It is fixed now. Hope it helps!